# Cropping a Pixel Buffer

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I am using the following to turn image data from the camera into a UIImage.  In order to save some time, and memory, I'd like to crop the image data before I turn it into an UIImage.

Ideally I pass in a cropRect, and get back a cropped UIImage.  However, since the camera output could be sized differently based on whether I am using a photo or video preset, I may not know what dimensions to use for the cropRect.  I could use a cropRect, similar to the focus or exposure points, that uses a CGPoint between (0,0) and (1,1) and do similarly for the CGSizeof the cropRect.  Or I can get the dimensions of the sampleBuffer, before I call the following, and pass in an appropriate cropRect.  I'd like some advice as to which I should use.

I also would like to know how best to crop in order not to have to create an entire UIImage and then crop it back down.  Typically, I am only interested in keeping about 10-20% of the pixels.  I assume I have to iterate through the pixels, and start copying the cropRect into a different pixel buffer, until I have all the pixels I want.

And keep in mind that there is possible rotation happening according to `orientation`.

```
+ (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer orientation:(UIImageOrientation) orientation
{
    // Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, 
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context); 
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage scale:(CGFloat)1.0 orientation:orientation];
    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}
```

In summary:

1. Should I pass in a cropRect which specifies a rect between (0,0,0,0) and (1,1,1,1) or do I pass in a cropRect that specifies exact pixel locations like (50,50,100,100)?
2. How best do I crop the pixel buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use pixel as cropRect, as you have to convert the float-values to pixel-values at least at some point. 
The following code is not tested, but should give you the idea.

```
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100); // cropRect
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVReturn lock = CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
if (lock == kCVReturnSuccess) {
    int w = 0;
    int h = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int bytesPerPixel = 0;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    w = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
    h = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
    r = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
    bytesPerPixel = r/w;
    buffer = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cropRect.size); // create context for image storage, use cropRect as size
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    unsigned char* data = CGBitmapContextGetData(c);
    if (data != NULL) {
        // iterate over the pixels in cropRect
        for(int y = cropRect.origin.y, yDest = 0; y<CGRectGetMaxY(cropRect); y++, yDest++) { 
            for(int x = cropRect.origin.x, xDest = 0; x<CGRectGetMaxX(cropRect); x++, xDest++) {
                int offset = bytesPerPixel*((w*y)+x); // offset calculation in cropRect
                int offsetDest = bytesPerPixel*((cropRect.size.width*yDest)+xDest); // offset calculation for destination image
                for (int i = 0; i<bytesPerPixel; i++) {
                    data[offsetDest+i]   = buffer[offset+i];
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: Close, I think.  Looks like it reads a little less for a row each time, so I get diagonal banding.  I'll debug it later tonight.  Things I have to watch out for:  the images are coming from the camera so they're all oriented landscape right (you have turn it 90° right to align with my view's x,y).  Also the images are big, so the cropRect used above is tiny - I need to translate that crop rect from my view's dimensions to the image's dimension.  I'll post any corrections back here.

Comment: I'm on the right track.  There are 12 bytes of padding on each row.  The rows are padded to multiples of 32?  The following line corrects the image, but my coordinates are still off (but that's a simple translation, I think):` int offset = bytesPerPixel*(((w+12)*y)+x); // offset calculation in cropRect`  The better fix is:`int offset = bytesPerPixel*x + r*y; // offset calculation in cropRect`

Should the destination pixbuff be 32 byte aligned too?